# EOF in C, what is EOF?

Tags: c, windows, eof

I have some questions about EOF in C.

1. What is actually EOF? I have read that it is a macro that "expands" to -1. What does this mean? Specifcally what does "expand" mean in this case?

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    scanf("%d", &c);
    if (c==EOF){printf("c is EOF");}
    else {printf("C is not EOF");}
}
```

Output:

```
1
C is not EOF
    
-1
c is EOF
    
^Z
```

2. In the code, if I write -1, I get that this is EOF. But from what I have read, EOF is not really -1, because we can write -1 at the end of a file?
3. I have read that on windows to get EOF you need to type CTRL+Z. But when I try to type this and press enter in the terminal, nothing happens, as I demonstrate in the last example in the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to re-read how `scanf` handles `EOF`. It does not assign it to the parsed parameter, but it **returns** it to the caller. If you put `-1` at the end of your file, you will read `-1` and the return value will be `1`, not `EOF`

Comment: It's symbolic value. So in that sense, it's not -1. From the manpage of scanf: "The value EOF is returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such as an end-of-file occurs.". EOF stands for end-of-file. But even a symbolic value will be expressed in bits; which often happens to be the same bits that represent the integer value -1.

Comment: "Expanding to -1" means, that everywhere in your code, where you write `EOF`, it will be replaced by `-1` by the preprocessor. It is just a macro that is expanded like any other macro. "Expand" just means "replace"

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh and 9769953. Do you mean that at the end of the file, EOF returns the value -1 to the caller?

Comment: Sorry I meant scanf, does scanf return -1?

Comment: scanf returns EOF. Which in probably all cases equals -1, but you shouldn't use that and just compare to the return value of scanf to EOF.

Comment: @tripleee No, but I have gotten a lot of good answers in this post right here. All I am missing is an answer to question 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is actually EOF? I have read that it is a macro that "expands" to
> -1. What does this mean? Specifically what does "expand" mean in this case?

It means that it is defined as C macro for example:

```
#define EOF -1
```

What is `EOF`?

`EOF` indicates that the **last** operation on the file or stream has reached its end.

The C preprocessor textually replaces occurrences of the `EOF` in your source code with `-1`

Your code is wrong. `scanf` **returns** `EOF` not scans it. It should be:

```
int main()
{
    int c, val;
    c = scanf("%d", &val);
    if (c==EOF){printf("c is EOF");}
    else {printf("C is not EOF");}
}
```

But `scanf` will almost never return `EOF` unless you provide a special key combination to force it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried running a version of your code where I print c after I have written c = scanf.... But when I print it the printout is "1", why is it not "-1"?

Comment: @user394334 Because scanf read 1 (!) character correctly. Please do read the manual for scanf: it returns the number of entries that were correctly read, and EOF if it encounters the end of a file (or end of input, with e.g. control-z or control-d).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing several concepts and layers.

Let's start at the top:

#### What is EOF?

EOF means End of file. That's when you hit the end of a file on the file system.

#### How is EOF signalled?

That depends on the function you use.

When using `read()`, it means you have a "short read": if you try to read 1024 bytes, but only get 400, you are likely at the end of the file. But you can only be sure if ou read again and you get 0 bytes.

Under Linux, pressing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> when reading from the console just stops the current `read()` call which might result in a "short read()". Pressing it a second time leads to `read()` returning 0.

There are other ways of reading, that are `getc()` and `scanf()`.

`getc()` returns an int: either the code of the character which was read, or if there is nothing to read, it returns -1 which is the value of `EOF`.

`scanf()`, however, just returns fewer elements or none at all. In the latter case, it retuens -1  / EOF in order to signal that `feof()` and/or `ferror()` should be checked. Details can be read in any decent description of that function.

Comment: `scanf(), however, just returns fewer elements` it is not the truth. EOF condition is signalled different way

Comment: @gulpr If EOF is encountered in the file, the successfully read elements are returned. The next attempt to read results in an `EOF`.